# How to compute the complexity of this?

Tags: c, algorithm, complexity-theory

```
int foo(int n)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for(int k=1; k <= n; k = k * 2) 
    {
        sum += k;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

I have the following function. 
Now, according to me the runtime complexity of foo(n) should be big-o(logn). 
Now, I am asked to find out the run time complexity of foo(n*n*n*n). What should it be?
According to me, it should be, big-o(logn) only.
Am I right in saying this?

Comment: I am asked to find out the run time complexity of foo(n*n*n*n).What does it means?

Comment: What is the reason of donwvoting the question, I don't understand?

Comment: No reason to downvote, +1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is O(log n<sup>4</sup>) → O(4 log n) → O(log n)

Comment: Yes, I did it by that way only. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 4):

Ask yourself, how many times does the loop execute? Create a table for the loop when the input is `n`:

```
for(int k=1; k <= n; k = k * 2)
```

---

```
  Iteration  |  k 
-------------+-----
      1      |  1
      2      |  2
      3      |  4
     ...     | ...
     ...     | ...
      k      |  n
```

2<sup>k</sup> = n → k = log(n)

Now you're asking for n<sup>4</sup> input. Simply change the table to:

```
  Iteration  |  k 
-------------+-----
      1      |  1
      2      |  2
      3      |  4
     ...     | ...
     ...     | ...
      k      | n^4
```

2<sup>k</sup> = n<sup>4</sup> → k = log(n<sup>4</sup>) = 4 * log(n)

Comment: @PaulR I'm giving OP a direction, not a full solution. I think my example should guide him to reach the answer.

Comment: He's already solved this part - read the whole question carefully.

Comment: I think it will be 8 corresponding to 3. However, it will be big-o(logn) for n^4 as well, right?

Comment: Well done - down-vote removed. I think there are some typos in your tables though, so no up-vote yet.

Comment: @PaulR Just fixed everything, I guess :) Let me know if there's something still wrong, thanks for pointing out to that.

Comment: I think the k column should be 1, 2, 4, 8, ..., n, no ?

Comment: I think k is just doubled on every iteration, so it starts at 1 and then becomes, 2, 4, 8, etc. that's why it's log n, since there will be log2 n iterations.

Comment: @PaulR Not it's correct thanks to abc edit. Coffee :)

Comment: All good now - have an up-vote - sometimes the simplest questions can be the fiddliest! ;-)

Comment: Please note that the value of k after iteration i is actually 2^(i-1). So if k becomes equal to n after i iterations then the loop ran for i times which is the complexity of the code. 2^(i-1) = n, and now you can solve this for i.